# Virtualenv, Django and corrupted paths

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm not even sure that I know what to ask or how.

I've been using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with Django for years and this is the first time that I've had this issue.

When I try to do something in my VE it is pulling in a file from a different project. I can't figure out where and the stacktrace doesn't make any sense. All the paths look right when I fire up Python and then take a look at sys.path.

I'm really looking for advice about how to troubleshoot the issue. Something is being cached and I can't find where.

Comment: If it's in a git repo or something, can you make a fresh virtualenv and redownload the source into it to see if that also has the same issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what to post. That's the problem. I'm trying to run management commands and they are pulling in from a different project.

Comment: commands are pulling what?

Comment: I've tried making new VEs and they don't work Same error persists.

Comment: For instance, any management command is pulling from an entirely different project somewhere.

Comment: @DaveMerwin this is crazy and cannot be true. you are confused. get some coffee, restart your machine and try again

Comment: @doniyor I wish I could favorite your comment. That is EXACTLY how I feel. BTW, I've done all that.

Comment: Well it sounds like you maybe have activated the wrong virtualenv at some point and installed into it. What happens if you make a new env and run your code from there?

Comment: Ok, I think I found a possible link. When I change my includes from relative to absolute the error goes away. So instead of `from . import views` I do `from myproject.myapp import views` the error goes away. Which indicates to me that the relative paths are messed up. So where would I change that?

Comment: You don't even have to activate the env just use the right python. E.g. cd to the dir with manage.py and then `env/bin/python manage.py runserver`. Does that work?

Comment: Is this in development or in production with multiple sites?

Comment: It's in development, but it's got me thinking about production.

Comment: Can you fire up the Django shell? `path/to/my/env/bin/python manage.py shell` than `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Comment: And post the stacktrace, used folder structure, your INSTALLED_APPS, the commands to create the envs. Pythons that you use. Double check the Python `which python`. Double check the pip command. When installing the packages, check if the paths are as expected...

Comment: Did you move something in your project? Eg. settings.py to some folder?